# Can a mouse use acceleration to track movement?

Tags: acceleration

Would it be technologically possible to use mouse momentum measurements to move a cursor on screen instead of the classic laser technology, without losing precision?

This would for example allow elegant wireless rings, that would transfer the motion of finger into the cursor on computer or smart tv display.

Comment: I think this is how Samsung Smart TV remotes work already?

Answer (score 2):

In principle yes, it can be done. It would be enough to put a MEMS accelerometer inside anything with an MCU and the rf component.

The device should work like an Inertial Measurement Unit (IMU) which might not be the simplest thing to do. Still you need to keep track of movements just for a few seconds and this can be done easily through simple integration, drifts and errors shouldn’t be nothing too high to be considered that much.

Adding a gyroscope(often inside the same MEMS) you can get full 3D orientation details.

Edit: you would then need to realize a usb dongle like any other wireless mouse to connect it to any computer

Comment: it's how VR controllers and Wii controllers work.